# Provide latest jars for salesforce.wsc & wsc

Tags: java

We are using below two sales force jars and those old versions.

1. wsc-23.jar
2. salesforce.wsc-1.1.jar

Not able find new version of above jars .  Please let me know if any one having idea about new jars or any replacement jars.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: are there any new versions of these jars available?